# Create virtual nodes and relatonships or use create virtual path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This cypher fragment unwinds a list of maps and creates virtual nodes and relations using `apoc.create.vNode`
and `apoc.create.vRelationship`. The execution of this script returns an arbitrary length path of virtual nodes.
Am I wrong to think that

```
apoc.create.virtualPath(labelsN :: LIST? OF STRING?, n :: MAP?, relType :: STRING?, props :: MAP?, labelsM :: LIST? OF STRING?, m :: MAP?) :: (from :: NODE?, rel :: RELATIONSHIP?, to :: NODE?)
```

is inappropriate because I first create virtual nodes?  Meaning, `apoc.create.virtualPath` is applied to concrete nodes only?

Here is my code:

```
UNWIND RANGE(0, size(vNodeListt)-1) AS i
    WITH vNodeListt[i] AS node1
    WITH CASE WHEN node1.label IN ["web","mobile"] 
    THEN apoc.create.vNode([node1.label],{session:node1.session,iTime:node1.iTime,pages:node1.pages}) 
    WHEN node1.label IN ["patron"]
    THEN apoc.create.vNode([node1.label],{eventTupple:node1.eventTupple,id:node1.id})
    ELSE apoc.create.vNode([node1.label],{interactionTime:node1.interactionTime})
    END AS vNode
    WITH COLLECT(vNode) AS vNodeList
    UNWIND RANGE(0, size(vNodeList)-2) AS i
    WITH vNodeList[i] AS event1, vNodeList[i+1] AS event2
    RETURN event1,event2,apoc.create.vRelationship(event1,'NEXT',{isNext:"TRUE"},event2)
```

Comment: Is this function implemented?   RETURN  apoc.create.virtualPath(["a"],{p1:1,p2:2},'knows',{r1:1},["b"],{p1:1,p2:2}) 
Unknown function 'apoc.create.virtualPath' (line 1, column 9 (offset: 8))

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.
However the `apoc.create.virtualPath` creates a virtual path without using or creating real nodes, so is quite similar to your `unwind range...` query.
In your case it gives error because it is a procedure, not a function, so you have to execute it with call, so:
call apoc.create.virtualPath(["a"],{p1:1,p2:2},'knows',{r1:1},["b"],{p1:1,p2:2})